# how to run sql query on delta table

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, delta-lake

I have problem with delta lake docs. I know that I can query on delta table with presto,hive,spark sql and other tools but in delta's documents mentioned that "You can load a Delta table as a DataFrame by specifying a table name or a path"

[image: from delta lake]

but it isn't clear. how can I run sql query like that?

Comment: running from where?

Comment: running from python

Answer (score 2):

Use the `spark.sql()` function

```
spark.sql("select * from delta.`hdfs://192.168.2.131:9000/Delta_Table/test001`").show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer by @OneCricketeer works, you can also read delta table to df, than create TempView from it and query that view:

```
df = spark.read.load(table_path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('delta_table_temp')
df1 = spark.sql('select * from delta_table_temp')
df1.show(10, False)
```

Comment: You should also be able to use `spark.table('delta_table_temp')` here instead of typing out `select *`

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes but question was how to run SQL on the table, "select *" was chosen just for example

Comment: The dataframe api writes optimized sql for you

Answer (score -2):

To read data from tables in DeltaLake it is possible to use Java API or Python **without Apache Spark**. See details at:
https://databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/natively-query-your-delta-lake-with-scala-java-and-python.html

See how to use with Pandas:

```sh
pip3 install deltalake
python3
```

```py
from deltalake import DeltaTable
table_path = "/opt/data/delta/my-table" # whatever table name and object store
# now using Pandas
df = DeltaTable(table_path).to_pandas()
df
```